# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when using Apache FileUpload

Tags: java, file-upload, noclassdeffounderror

I am using Apache FileUpload and I am getting a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

My first thought was to check whether the .jar was on the classpath - what I notice (in Eclipse) is that under the libraries area, there are two different sections:

- Apache Tomcat v6.0
- Web App Libraries

All the other libraries are listed under "Web App Libraries" and this particular library is listed under Apache Tomcat v6.0

I am assuming this is causing the problem ... my code is here below ... but I think it's a config issue rather than a code issue.

Finally - the web.xml is not the problem as I have taken out the FileUpload stuff from the servlet and the servlet gets found just fine.

```
public class SaveImage extends HttpServlet{

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Got here");
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
}
```

Comment: This *has* to be classpath issue. What your IDE thinks is on the classpath is not as important as what the web server thinks is on the classpath. What's in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder after your app is deployed (in the deployment target directory)?

Comment: The thing is the testing servlet container is built into Eclipse, hence whatever Eclipse thinks is on the classpath is what Tomcat will get (hope that makes sense). But thanks for clearing that up, I know where to look for issues now.

Comment: Thanks Asaph, you were right, it's all solved now. Basically I need to remove some things which had gone onto the Tomcat build path and read them to the "Web App Libraries" build path

Comment: You can copy commons fileupload jars and dependencies into <tomcat_root>/lib folder. As @Asaph said, copying libraries into lib folder of application,does automatically set the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *has* to be a classpath issue. What your IDE thinks is on the classpath is not as important as what the web server thinks is on the classpath. What's in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder after your app is deployed (in the deployment target directory)? That's what the real classpath is (plus the web server's libs, of course).